# Can $n^7+7$ be a perfect cube if $n\geq2$?

Tags: number-theory

$n^7+7$ is only a perfect cube when $n=1$.

Using Mathematica, I checked the values of $n\leq10^4$, but no numbers listed there is perfect cube.

Can $n^7+7$ be a perfect cube if $n\geq2$?

I think $n^7+7$ can be a perfect cube if $n\geq2$, since:

$n^7+7\equiv8\pmod{9}$ if $n\equiv1,2\pmod{9}$

$n^7+7\equiv\pm1\pmod{7}$ if $n\equiv1\pmod{7}$

$n^7+7\equiv1,5,8\pmod{13}$ if $n\equiv1,2,6,8\pmod{13}$

Comment: why do those congruences mean it should be possibly a cube?

Comment: That a polynomial like $x^7  + 7$ has cube values mod $m$ for all $m$ does not imply $x^7 + 7$ has to have a cube value in $\mathbf Z$ for some $x \not= 1$.  Here's an analgoue. When $k$ is a nonzero integer the congruence $y^2 \equiv x^3 + k \bmod m$ has a solution for each $m$ (See my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134352/the-modular-arithmetic-contradiction-trick-for-diophantine-equations), but that doesn't mean the equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ has to have an integral solution. For instance, $y^2 = x^3 + 7$ has no integral solution.

Comment: See [Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).  Many cases are known, maybe $k, k+7$ is known.  In any case, these tend to be hard problems.

Comment: Don't state things as fact which you don't know. Your first sentence is a statement of fact, but you don't know if it is true. If you wanted it to be a question, make it a question.

Comment: @lulu In fact only ONE case is actually solved , namely difference $1$ ($8/9$ is the only solution)

Comment: @Peter   Really?  I thought some small cases were known...but I can't find any references to back that up.  The proof of Catalan doesn't extend at all?

Comment: For $a,b\ge 2$, the equation $a^3-b^7=c$ has a solution for $c=10$, namely $13^3-3^7=10$. For $c=7$ it is conjectured that there is no solution with $a,b\ge 2$. There are papers by Bennett about it, I think.

Comment: The only non-negative integer $n\le 10^8$ , for which $n^7+7$ is a perfect power is $1$ as a brute force test with PARI/GP revealed.

Comment: The non-negative integers $n$ such that both $n$ and $n+7$ are a perfect power , are : $$9\ 25\ 121\ 32761$$ and no other upto $10^9$

Comment: I think , wikipdedia gives more details under Pillai's conjecture. You can look it up , but be prepared for new annoying donation appeals.

Comment: @lulu Note that massive computational effort was necessary to solve the apparently special case with difference $1$ completely (of course together with a genuine proof using the results of the long computations). The other cases have been checked upto high limits of course , but for all I know , all cases except $d=1$ are open. Wikipedia stated this the last time I looked up the conjecture , in the mean time something new might have been discovered.

Comment: For $n^7+7=k^3$, working $\bmod 8$, it can be shown that for any possible solutions, either $n\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ and $k$ is even, or $n$ is even and $k\equiv 7 \bmod 8$

Comment: @Peter Perhaps I misunderstand your comment, but the case $a^m-b^n=1$ was solved without any computational effort.

Comment: @Servaes If I am informed right , the computational effort (before the proof) made it likely that the conjecture is true and was enough to reduce the problem in such a way that it could be solved completely. I might be wrong , I have never seen the proof ,maybe the new version is better and does not need the work before.

Comment: For $n^7+7=k^3$, $7\mid n \iff 7\mid k$. But if $7\mid n$, then LHS has only one factor of $7$ and RHS has at least $3$ factors of $7$. So $7\not \mid n$. Working $\bmod 7$ we obtain $n\equiv k^3 \bmod 7$. The non-zero values of cubes $\bmod 7$ are $\pm 1$, whence for any solution, it must be true that $n\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 7$

Answer (score 1):

Not a strict proof, but we know that any perfect cube is congruent to $\{0,1,8\} \pmod 9$. Then, we observe that $n^7+7 \equiv \{0,2,3,5,6,7,8\} \pmod 9$. In particular, we have that a necessary but not sufficient condition for $n^7+7$ to be a perfect cube is that $n \equiv \{1,2\} \pmod {10}$. Then, you have added two additional constraints that improve the aforementioned approach and this is correct.

On the other hand, $n^7+7$ is a perfect cube if and only if $(-1)^{\frac{2}{7}} (m^3 - 7)^{\frac{1}{7}} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for some $m$ running over the positive integers. And thus, in order to prove that $n=1$ is the only solution, we have to check that $\sqrt[7]{m^3-7}$ is integer if and only if $m=2$ ($m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$).

According to W.A., the above has only a unique solution, thus we have a perfect cube only if $n=1 \wedge n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: I don't think W.A. can give a proof here.

Comment: W.A. cannot prove this, otherwise we would have got a strict proof and this is not the case. We can combine some constraints in order to reduce the number of cases to be checked up to a given limit and the odds to get a counterexample become smaller and smaller as the lower bound grows, but this is not a method to find a final answer. I haven't spent much time thinking about the problem... so, the conjecture could be proven/disproven by using simple math or not, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer. This is an attempt at a standard approach, which ends up getting a bit cumbersome and involved. I did not want this to get lost so I'm posting it here for now, I may continue this at a later point.

---

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that
$$n^7+7=m^3.$$
Then in the ring of integers $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ you have
$$n^7=m^3-7=(m+\sqrt[3]{7})(m^2-\sqrt[3]{7}m-\sqrt[3]{7}^2).$$
Unfortunately $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is not a unique factorization domain, but for the ideals
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathfrak{n}&:=&(n),\\
\mathfrak{m}&:=&(m+\sqrt[3]{7}),\\
\mathfrak{m}'&:=&(m^2-\sqrt[3]{7}m-\sqrt[3]{7}^2),
\end{eqnarray}
we have $\mathfrak{n}^7=\mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{m}'$, and clearly $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}'$ contains
$$(m^2-\sqrt[3]{7}m-\sqrt[3]{7}^2)-(m-2\sqrt[3]{7})(m+\sqrt[3]{7})=\sqrt[3]{7}^2.$$
Of course $n$ is not divisible by $7$ and so $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}'$ are coprime, which means that there exist coprime ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathfrak{n}&=&\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b},\\
\mathfrak{m}&=&\mathfrak{a}^7,\\
\mathfrak{m}'&=&\mathfrak{b}^7.
\end{eqnarray}
The class group of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is cyclic of order $3$ generated by the unique prime $\mathfrak{p}_3:=(1-\sqrt[3]{7},3)$ over $3$. Because $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}'$ are both principal, this means $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are also principal. So we have
\begin{eqnarray}
m+\sqrt[3]{7}&=&\eta^k(u+v\sqrt[3]{7}+w\sqrt[3]{7}^2)^7,\\
m^2-\sqrt[3]{7}m-\sqrt[3]{7}^2&=&\eta^{-k}(x+y\sqrt[3]{7}+z\sqrt[3]{7}^2)^7,
\end{eqnarray}
for some integers $k,u,v,w,x,y,z\in\Bbb{Z}$, where $\eta\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is the fundamental unit
$$\eta:=4+2\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt[3]{7}^2,$$
and without loss of generality $0\leq k<7$. With $\eta^{-1}=2-\sqrt[3]{7}$ we can rearrange the first identity as
$$(m+\sqrt[3]{7})(2-\sqrt[3]{7})^k=(u+v\sqrt[3]{7}+w\sqrt[3]{7}^2)^7.\tag{1}$$
Define $a_k,b_k,c_k\in\Bbb{Z}$ as the coefficients of the left hand side of the identity above, so that
$$a_k+b_k\sqrt[3]{7}+c_k\sqrt[3]{7}^2:=(m+\sqrt[3]{7})(2-\sqrt[3]{7})^k.$$
A bit of algebra yields the values
\begin{array}{r|rrr}
k&a_k&b_k&c_k\\
\hline
0&m&1&0\\
1&2m&-m+2&-1\\
2&4m+7&-4m+4&m-4\\
3&6m-12&-12m+1&m+42\\
4&24m-25&-25m-40&-40m+168\\
5&73m-10&-10m-248&-248m+511\\
6&156m+228&228m-1007&-1007m+1092\\
\end{array}
A bit more cumbersome algebra, after expanding the right hand side of $\tag{1}$, yields
Expanding the right hand side yields, after a fair bit of cumbersome algebra, the identities
\begin{eqnarray}
a_k&=&u^7+294u^5vw+245u^4v^3+1715u^4w^3+10290u^3v^2w^2+5145u^2v^4w+36015u^2vw^4\\
&\ &+343uv^6+48020uv^3w^3+16807uw^6+7203v^5w^2+50421v^2w^5,\\
b_k&=&7u^6v+147u^5w^2+735u^4v^2w+245u^3v^4+6860u^3vw^3+10290u^2v^33w^2\\
&\ &+7203u^2w^5+2058uv^5w+36015uv^2w^4+49v^7+12005v^4w^3+16807vw^6,\\
c_k&=&u^6w+21u^5v^2+735u^4vw^2+980u^3v^3w+1715u^3v^4+147u^2v^5+10290u^2v^2w^3\\
&\ &+5145uv^4w^2+14406uvw^5+343v^6w+12005v^3w^4+2401w^7.\\
\end{eqnarray}

- For $k=0$ we see that $b_k=1$, but the expansion above shows that $b_k\equiv0\pmod{7}$. So there is no solution with $k=0$.
- For $k=1$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv2\pmod{7}$.
  Then from $a_k$ we see that $u\equiv2\pmod{7}$, and then from $c_k$
  we see that $w\equiv-1\pmod{7}$. [...to be continued...]
- For $k=2$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv1\pmod{7}$. Then from $a_k$
  we see that $u\equiv4\pmod{7}$, and then from $c_k$ we see that
  $w\equiv4\pmod{7}$. [...to be continued...]
- For $k=3$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv3\pmod{7}$. Then from $a_k$ we see that $u\equiv6\pmod{7}$ and then from $c_k$ we see that $w\equiv3\pmod{7}$. [...to be continued...]
- For $k=4$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv3\pmod{7}$. Then from $a_k$ we see that $u\equiv5\pmod{7}$, and then from $c_k$ we see that $w\equiv6\pmod{7}$. [...to be continued...]
- For $k=5$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv6\pmod{7}$. Then from $a_k$ we see that $u\equiv1\pmod{7}$, and then from $c_k$ we see that $w\equiv3\pmod{7}$. [...to be continued...]
- For $k=6$ we see from $b_k$ that $m\equiv5\pmod{7}$. Then from $a_k$
  we see that $u\equiv0\pmod{7}$ and hence $c_k\equiv0\pmod{7}$. But this contradicts $c_k=-1007m+1092\equiv5\pmod{7}$. So there is no solution with $k=6$.

A next step would be to tackle the cases $k=1,\ldots,5$ through $7$-adic arguments, perhaps. I'll leave it at this for now, and may return later.

Comment: For some basic properties of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ see this blurb by Keith Conrad:
https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/Qw7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- $x^7+7=y^3\iff x^7-1=y^3-8$ so we have
$$\frac{x-1}{y^2+2y+4}=\frac{y-2}{x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1}$$ For rational integers, we have necessarily, for some $n\in\mathbb Z$,
$$y-2=n(x-1)\\x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=n(y^2+2y+4)$$
Then, coming to the initial equation, we have to solve $$x^7+7-(nx+2-n)^3=0$$ According with WOLFRAM the only real root is $x=1$ which correspond to the known solution $(x,y)=(1,2)$. If we want to prove this we need to prove the irrreducibility over $\mathbb Q$ for all $n$ of the polynomial
$$x^7-n^3x^3-3n^2(n-2)x^2+3n(n^2-4n+4)x-(n^3-6n^2+12n-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach that is too long for a comment, but short of a rigorous proof:**

Start with $n^7+7=m^3$. The solution $n=1,m=2$ is given, but are there solutions for $n>1$? With that restriction, we observe $n^2<m<n^3$ from which we can say $m=an^2+b$ where $1\le a<n,1\le b<n^2$

Restate the problem: $n^7=(an^2+b)^3-7$. If we expand and divide through by $n^2$, all terms in the resulting equation are explicitly integers except $\frac{b^3-7}{n^2}$, which must implicitly be an integer. Setting that term equal to some integer $c$, we get $b^3-cn^2-7=0$. I note that this equation is similar to, but not exactly in the standard form of, an elliptic curve.

According to Wolfram Alpha (so not a rigorous proof), the only integer solution to $b^3-cn^2-7=0$ with $n>1,b\ge 1$ is $b=3,c=5,n=2$. But $n=2$ is not a solution to the original equation. Unless there are integer solutions to $b^3-cn^2-7=0$ that are beyond W.A.'s ability to locate readily, there are no solutions to $n^7+7=m^3$ with $n>1$

**Note:** When W.A. is queried about the above equation using $d+2$ in place of $n$ (to ensure that solutions with $n>2$ are searched for), it returns no integer solutions.